# Scraping data from a website using scrapy

Tags: css, python-3.x, scrapy

I am trying to scrape data from a website using scrapy. This is the css path

```
<div _ngcontent-amb-c25="" appcoloredmultiplier="" class="bubble-multiplier font-weight-bold" style="padding: 2px 11px; border-radius: 11px; color: rgb(52, 180, 255);"> 1.21x </div>
```

but I'd like to extract data between the  tag which is 1.21x how do I update my code to extract the data I stated.

```
def parse(self, response):
# Extract game history data from the webpage
game_history_elements = response.css('div.bubble-multiplier')

# Extract the multiplier value from each game history element
game_history = [re.search(r'(\d+\.\d+)x', element.css('::text').get()).group(1) for element in game_history_elements]

# Print the game history data
print(game_history)
```

Comment: why dont you just extract text from `div.bubble-multiplier` ?

Comment: I am trying to extract the text in element.css('::text').get() but it is returning nothing

Comment: @PhulusoRamulifho, `response.css('div.bubble-multiplier::text').getall()` should return a list of all the matching strings. If not maybe there's a problem with the selector, in this case you should share the url.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you can get the text between tags using the `::text` css directive in your xpath expression and then applying either the `get` or `getall` methods on the selector.

If there is more than one `div` with the class `bubble-multiplier`, and you want the text for each of them then you would use `getall()`, on the other hand if there is only a single matching element or you simply only want the first, then you would use `getall()`.

```
def parse(self, response):
    game_history = response.css('div.bubble-multiplier::text').get()
    print(game_history)
```

or

```
def parse(self, response):
    game_history = response.css('div.bubble-multiplier::text').getall()
    print(game_history)
```

You can still use `getall` when there is only a single match, the only difference would be that the the return value would be a `list` with just the one string as contents.